# How do I change the puppet version installed by vagrant

Tags: puppet, vagrant

I use vagrant 1.0.1 on a precise32 base box to play with puppet.
Provisioning works fine, my manifests are being executed.
By default vagrant installs puppet 2.7.14 under /opt/vagrant_ruby/bin/puppet on the guest.

How can I configure vagrant (or who ever installs puppet on the guest) to use a more recent version like puppet 3.0 or 3.1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to rebuild the basebox that you are using in vagrant and install whatever version of Puppet you want. I did the same for Cent 6.3 w/puppet 3.0. The [Veewee gem](https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee) is a great utility to building and managing Vagrant baseboxes for Oracle Virtualbox.

Comment: I was not aware that puppet and chef came with the box. I thought they would be installed only if the according provisioner was configured in the vagrant file. Thx for pointing it out.

Answer (score 10):

Also you could update puppet with shell provisioner specified *before* puppet provisioner. As said in [Vagrant documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/basic_usage.html):

> Multiple `config.vm.provision` methods can be used to define multiple provisioners. These provisioners will be run in the order they're defined. This is useful for a variety of reasons, but most commonly it is used so that a shell script can bootstrap some of the system so that another provisioner can take over later.

Here is example Vagrantfile for [CentOS 6](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/puppetlabs_package_repositories.html#for-red-hat-enterprise-linux-and-derivatives):

```
# Update puppet to version 3.2.2 before using puppet provisioning.
$puppet_update_script = <<SCRIPT
[ `rpm -qa puppetlabs-release` = 'puppetlabs-release-6-7.noarch' ] || rpm -ivh http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/6/products/i386/puppetlabs-release-6-7.noarch.rpm 
[ `rpm -qa puppet` = 'puppet-3.2.2-1.el6.noarch' ] || yum -y update-to puppet-3.2.2
SCRIPT
config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => $puppet_update_script

# Puppet-3.2.2 provisioning here
config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
  puppet.options = '--parser future'
  puppet.manifests_path = 'puppet/manifests'
end
```